Aligning Text in SwiftUI Horizontally
I have text coming from an API call. I want to display it. The issue is as below:
Dummy data provided to run
struct SampleTypeBox: View {
    
    var sampleType : [SampleTypeList]
VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 20){
            HStack{
            ForEach(sampleType.indices,id:\.self){sample in
                Text("\(sample+1)." + "\(sampleType[sample].SampleName)")
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                }
                
            }

struct SampleTypeBox_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       let SampleList =
    [
        SampleTypeList(
            TestSampleTypeId: "50",
            SampleName: "2 ml Serum",
            ColourCode: "#FFB500"
        ),
        SampleTypeList(
            TestSampleTypeId: "55",
            SampleName: "EDTA Whole Blood",
            ColourCode: "#FFB500"
        ),
        SampleTypeList(
            TestSampleTypeId: "55",
            SampleName: "EDTA Whole Blood",
            ColourCode: "#FFB500"),
        SampleTypeList(
            TestSampleTypeId: "55",
            SampleName: "EDTA Whole Blood",
            ColourCode: "#FFB500"),
        SampleTypeList(
            TestSampleTypeId: "55",
            SampleName: "EDTA Whole Blood",
            ColourCode: "#FFB500")
        
    ]
        SampleTypeBox(sampleType: SampleList)
    }
}

I have attached pic. The green shows what I am getting and the red color output is what I want.

Looks like you just want one single Text to display everything, not an HStack. Collect all the data into one String and put that in a Text. Is that what you want?

@Sweeper yes it worked as expected nice way to solve this annoying issue

Construct a single String from the list of samples, and create a single Text view with it.
Text(
    sampleList.enumerated().map { "\($0 + 1). \($1.sampleName)" }.joined(separator: " ")
)
.font(.system(size: 13))
.foregroundColor(.green)

...

struct SampleTypeList {
    let testSampleTypeId: String
    let sampleName: String
    let colourCode: String
}
let sampleList =
    [
        SampleTypeList(
            testSampleTypeId: "50",
            sampleName: "2 ml Serum",
            colourCode: "#FFB500"),
        SampleTypeList(
            testSampleTypeId: "55",
            sampleName: "EDTA Whole Blood",
            colourCode: "#FFB500"),
        SampleTypeList(
            testSampleTypeId: "55",
            sampleName: "EDTA Whole Blood",
            colourCode: "#FFB500"),
        SampleTypeList(
            testSampleTypeId: "55",
            sampleName: "EDTA Whole Blood",
            colourCode: "#FFB500"),
        SampleTypeList(
            testSampleTypeId: "55",
            sampleName: "EDTA Whole Blood",
            colourCode: "#FFB500")
    ]

If each part of the text should have different styles (font, text color, etc), you should still use one Text, but create a AttributedString instead of a regular String.
